# Find the closest key in a dictonary with string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to find a way to find the closest key to a string within a dictonary. Example:

```
data = {'1a': 'This is 1a', '1d': 'This is 1d', '1f': 'This is 1f', '1e': 'This is 1e'}
find_nearest(data, '1b')
#This would return key '1a'
```

I have found other examples, but most deal with numbers. Example:

```
data[num] if num in data else data[min(data.keys(), key=lambda k: abs(k-num))]
```

I was able to find one code that looked promising:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
sd = SortedDict((key, value) for key, value in data)

# Bisect for the index of the desired key.
index = sd.bisect(200)

# With that index, lookup the key.
key = sd.iloc[index]

# You can also look ahead or behind to find the nearest key.
behind = sd.iloc[index - 1]
ahead = sd.iloc[index + 1]
```

So I tried this, here is my code:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
data = {'1a': 'This is 1a', '1d': 'This is 1d', '1f': 'This is 1f', '1e': 'This is 1e'}
sd = SortedDict((key,value) for key,value in data.items())

index = sd.bisect('1b')

key = sd.iloc[index]
print(key)
```

But when I run this code it returns:

```
1d #Instead of '1a'
```

I have tried every which way to get the code to work, but i can't seem to get it right. Does anyone know of a fast and efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: The bisect function just does bisect_right, which gives you the right next value and not the closest.

Comment: Need to define what *closest* within your requirement mean?...like..what if there where `1a` and `1c`, what would you consider close?..and which you'll pick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bisect, the algorithm has 2 choices if it doesn't find an exact index match.  It can return the index of the object on the left, or the index of the object on the right.  It looks like `bisect` is an alias of `bisect_right`.  You could use [`bisect_left`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#SortedList.L.bisect_left) instead...

Of course, this isn't necessarily *closer* (you haven't really defined what you mean by closer).  Indeed, even something like `difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio()` probably won't help with the example as it only looks to see what the ratio of matching to non-matching elements are.

You could try something like:

```
def find_closest(sd, expected):
    index = sd.bisect(expected)
    closest_lower = sd.iloc[index]
    try: 
        closest_upper = sd.iloc[index]
    except IndexError:
        return closest_lower

    # assumption -- Your keys are hex values.
    # this assumption could be completely wrong, but demonstrates
    # how to think of defining a measure of "closeness"
    var expected_as_int = int(expected, 16)
    def distance(val):
        return int(val, 16) - expected_as_int

    return min([closest_lower, closest_upper], key=distance)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would implement this is by iterating through the keys in order, and finding the key with the smallest "difference".  Because the keys are sorted, you know you've found it as soon as the difference stops decreasing.

```
def closestKey(data, val):
    lastKey = None
    lastDif = None
    for key in sorted(data.keys()):
        dif = difference(key, val) #need to figure out difference()
        if lastDif is not None and dif > lastDif:
            return lastKey
        lastDif = dif
        lastKey = key
```

This doesn't handle the case in which two keys are equidistant, if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mgilson, that gave me the idea that helped me, I was able to do what I wanted to achieve. Here is my code for anyone interested:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
data = {'1a': 'This is 1a', '1d': 'This is 1d', '1g': 'This is 1g', '1h': 'This is 1h'}
def find_closest(sd, expected):
    index = sd.bisect(expected)
    try:
        indexAhead = sd.iloc[index]
    except IndexError:
        indexAhead = sd.iloc[len(sd.keys()) - 1]
    if indexAhead == expected:
        return expected
    else:

        try:
            indexBehindNum = 0
            indexBehind = sd.iloc[index -1]
            for char in indexBehind:
                indexBehindNum += ord(char)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        if not indexBehindNum:
            return indexAhead
        else:
            expectedTotalNum = 0
            indexAheadNum = 0
            for char in expected:
                expectedTotalNum += ord(char)
            for char in indexAhead:
                indexAheadNum += ord(char)
            diffrenceAhead = indexAheadNum - expectedTotalNum
            diffrenceBehind = indexBehindNum - expectedTotalNum
            Closest = min([diffrenceAhead, diffrenceBehind], key=abs)
            if Closest == diffrenceAhead:
                return indexAhead
            else:
                return indexBehind

sd = SortedDict((key,value) for key,value in data.items())

print(find_closest(sd, '1b'))#This will return '1a'!
```

I am not sure if this is the fastest and most efficient, but I will try to continue to try to find other ways.